# Using .insetGrouped listStyle for List in SwiftUI on iOS14.4 caused a data problem

Tags: swift, swiftui

The code can be downloaded in a tutorial from Apple, the link is here:
`https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/persisting-data`

Problem code:

```
struct ScrumsView: View {
    @Binding var scrums: [DailyScrum]
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State private var isPresented = false
    @State private var newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
    let saveAction: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(scrums) { scrum in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(scrum: binding(for: scrum))) {
                    CardView(scrum: scrum)
                }
                .listRowBackground(scrum.color)
            }
        }
        // Problem here
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .navigationTitle("Daily Scrums")
...
```

On iOS 14.4, I tried to set `listStyle` to any other style except `.sidebar` or `.automatic`, when I go to `MeetingView` and back to `DetailView`, the `History` section hasn't been updated. But if I use these code on iOS 15, there is no problem.

I found that if I use these style, when I pop back to `DetailView`,  the `onDisappear` closure in `MeetingView` would be executed, but the "History" section's `ForEach` function in `DetailView` wouldn't be executed.

Thanks for anyone who could help me to figiure out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle()) worked for me.